# Problem with complex eigenvalue in these Researches?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm very confused with the result of the complex eigenvalue in this Research

[A minimal model for studying properties of the mode-coupling type instability in friction induced oscillations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239369314)

It's about a vibration model call Hoffmann with the equations of motion:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\left( \frac { \ddot { x }  }{ \ddot { y }  }  \right) +\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1-\Delta  \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\left( \frac { x }{ y }  \right) =0
$$ And then they calculated the complex eigenvalue:
$${ s }_{ 1,2 }={ \pm \left[ 2\pm \sqrt { 1-\Delta  }  \right]  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }$$
I really don't undersatand how did they calculate this formula. Because i think the complex eigenvalue in this situation must be looked like this:
$${ s }_{ 1,2 }={ 2\pm \sqrt { 1-\Delta  }  }$$

Comment: Use `\pmatrix{ a \\ b}` to get $\pmatrix{a \\ b}$. See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: it seems to me $s_{1,2}$ are eigen-frequencies of the dynamical system, not eigenvalues of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $u = dx/dt$ and $v = dy/dt$, so that you can write the differential equations as

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &=& u \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &=& v \\
\frac{du}{dt} &=& -2x - (1 - \Delta)y \\
\frac{dv}{dt} &=& -x -2y
\end{eqnarray*}

or in matrix form

$$
\frac{dX}{dt} = A X,
$$

with $X = (x, y, u, v)^T$ and

$$
A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -2 & \Delta-1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -2 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The formal solution to this problem is

$$
X(t) = e^{A t}X(0)
$$

for which you need to find the eigenvalues of $A$:

$$
\pm[-2 \pm (1 -d)^{1/2}]^{1/2}
$$